# useLeafletContext() can only be used in a descendant of <MapContainer>

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am in the process of converting a leaflet-map in React into a hook with the use of react-leaflet and react-leaflet-markercluster. Everything worked perfectly except the use of the MarkerCluster component. The app gives this error:
`Error: No context provided: useLeafletContext() can only be used in a descendant of <MapContainer>`

I have tried to do the exact same thing as in this codesandbox, including using the same versions of the packages:
https://codesandbox.io/s/9binx?file=/src/styles.scss:168-206

Both in the existing project and a completely fresh one (create-react-app). It still gives the same error in the existing project. So did the fresh project, but was fixed when removing this from the package.json:

```
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
```

This was never in the existing project though. Here is the package.json for the existing project:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.4.0",
        "@sentry/react": "5.27.1",
        "@sentry/tracing": "5.27.1",
        "classnames": "^2.3.1",
        "http-proxy-middleware": "1.0.6",
        "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
        "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.1",
        "moment": "2.29.1",
        "normalize.css": "8.0.1",
        "rc-slider": "9.5.4",
        "react": "17.0.1",
        "react-app-polyfill": "2.0.0",
        "react-datepicker": "3.3.0",
        "react-dates": "21.8.0",
        "react-dom": "17.0.1",
        "react-html5-camera-photo": "1.5.4",
        "react-leaflet": "^3.2.1",
        "react-leaflet-markercluster": "^3.0.0-rc1",
        "react-markdown": "5.0.2",
        "react-query": "2.25.2",
        "react-redux": "7.2.2",
        "react-responsive-pinch-zoom-pan": "0.3.0",
        "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
        "react-select": "3.1.0",
        "redux": "4.0.5",
        "redux-actions": "2.6.5",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.8",
        "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
        "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
        "typescript": "4.0.5"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "BROWSER=NONE REACT_APP_DISABLE_LIVE_RELOAD=false react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "build--withStats": "react-scripts build --stats",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "test:coverage": "npm run test -- --coverage",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "analyze": "source-map-explorer build/static/js/main.*"
    },
    "lint-staged": {
        "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css}": [
            "prettier --single-quote --tab-width 4 --write"
        ]
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8080/",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@testing-library/dom": "7.26.3",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.11.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "11.1.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "12.1.10",
        "@tsconfig/recommended": "1.0.1",
        "@types/history": "4.7.2",
        "@types/jest": "26.0.15",
        "@types/leaflet": "^1.5.19",
        "@types/node": "14.14.5",
        "@types/react": "16.9.53",
        "@types/react-dom": "16.9.8",
        "@types/react-redux": "7.1.9",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
        "@types/redux-logger": "3.0.8",
        "fetch-mock": "^9.10.7",
        "fetch-mock-jest": "^1.3.0",
        "husky": "4.3.0",
        "jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen": "1.0.3",
        "lint-staged": "10.5.0",
        "msw": "0.21.3",
        "prettier": "2.1.2",
        "source-map-explorer": "2.5.0"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "jest": {
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
            "!<rootDir>/node_modules/",
            "!<rootDir>/integration-tests/",
            "!<rootDir>/public/",
            "!<rootDir>/build/"
        ],
        "coverageThreshold": {
            "global": {
                "branches": 90,
                "functions": 90,
                "lines": 90,
                "statements": 90
            }
        },
        "coverageReporters": [
            "text"
        ]
    }
}
```

Anyone have any clue as to what it could be that's causing the error?

Comment: hello, is there any updates? did you solve this?

Comment: Hi, no my team decided to abandon this and go for the classic leaflet js solution.

Answer (score 3):

In the `3.2.0` release of `react-leaflet`, the author of the library started using the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) which as I understand it breaks various bundlers including `create-react-app` when the MarkerCluster plugin pulls in the new `react-leaflet` as a peer dependency.

The CodeSandbox you linked is using version `3.0.2` and one fix is for you to use a `react-leaflet` version `<3.2.0` in your package.json

```
"react-leaflet": ">=3.1.0 <3.2.0",
"@react-leaflet/core": ">=1.0.0 <1.1.0"  // you may not need this one
```

Of course this will prevent you from picking up updates in the future, so you will need to check the [Github issues](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+useleafletcontext) periodically and see if a fix has been released.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same error message. In my case, there were multiple versions of `@react-leaflet/core` present in my project.

My `yarn.lock` file had 2 entries pointing to different versions:

```
"@react-leaflet/core@^1.0.2":
  version "1.1.0"
  ...

"@react-leaflet/core@^1.1.1":
  version "1.1.1"
  ...
```

I solved the issue by combining them into a single entry:

```
"@react-leaflet/core@^1.0.2", "@react-leaflet/core@^1.1.1":
  version "1.1.1"
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the problem by removing `react-leaflet-markercluster` and installing `@changey/react-leaflet-markercluster`.

Answer (score 0):

This last works for me, I just walk back to a previous react-leaflet version and the `useLeafletContext()` works as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of react.js wrappers you can use this.

```
import { FC, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import L from 'leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import 'leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.css'
import 'leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css'
require('leaflet.markercluster/dist/leaflet.markercluster-src')

const Map: FC = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        const map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13)
        L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: '© OpenStreetMap'
        }).addTo(map)

        const icon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2776/2776067.png',
            iconSize: [30, 30]
        })

        const markers = L.markerClusterGroup()
        const marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(38.423733, 27.142826), { icon })
        marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.")
        const marker2 = L.marker(new L.LatLng(38.453899, 27.211700), { icon })
        markers.addLayer(marker)
        markers.addLayer(marker2)
        map.addLayer(markers)
        return () => {
            map.off()
            map.remove()
        }
    }, [])

    return <div id='map'></div>
}

export default Map
`
```

Answer (score 0):

try `npm i @react-leaflet/core`

try npm install leaflet-draw